# mySQL INNER JOIN with 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables:

```
Stage:           ID, stage_name, stage_points, stage_number
Shooter:         ID, sh_uid, sh_al, sh_cat 
Stage_Shooters:  ID, StageID, ShooterID  
Score:           ID, miss, proc, bth, finalTime, shtr
Stage_Scores:    ID, StageID, ScoreID
```

Stage_Shooters and Stage_Scores are many_many relation for stated tables. e.g. Shooters are connected to the stages via Stage_Shooters.

I am trying to retrieve all the Shooter's scores for each stage.  Currently I have 5 stages and 28 shooters, so that makes for 140 Scores. I want it to look like this eventually:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shooter              | Stage Name                | Stage Name                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Alias       | Cat    | Raw   | M | P | B | Fin   | Raw   | M | P | B | Fin   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Short Round | Junior | 24.00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 19.00 | 7.00  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6.00  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Indy Jones  | Senior | 24.00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 22.00 | 4.00  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 12.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For this I figure I'll have to do a pivot table, but for now I'm just trying to get the following results:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Stage Name | Shooter Alias | Shooter Category | Raw | M | P | B | Fin |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Stage Name | Shooter Alias | Shooter Category | Raw | M | P | B | Fin |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I run the following sql I get 700 results instead of 140 (as expected)

```
SELECT ssh.stage_name, ssh.sh_al, ssh.sh_cat, ssc.time, ssc.M, ssc.P, ssc.B, ssc.Fin
FROM (
    SELECT s.stage_name, sh.sh_al, sh.sh_uid, sh.sh_cat
    FROM Shooter sh
    INNER JOIN Stage_Shooters stsh ON stsh.ShooterID = sh.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsh.StageID
) ssh
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.stage_name stageName, sc.time, sc.shtr, sc.miss M, sc.proc P, sc.bth B, sc.finalTime Fin
    FROM Score sc
    INNER JOIN Stage_Scores stsc ON stsc.ScoreID = sc.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsc.StageID
) ssc
WHERE ssh.sh_uid = ssc.shtr
ORDER BY ssh.sh_al
```

If I remove the WHERE statement I get 19600 results.
How can I use joins or sub queries to get just the 140 rows I need?

Comment: can you post some sample data for each table?  Even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have 3 recommendations:

### 1- You are not joining the data on corresponding Stage

If you add to the query `AND ssh.stage_name = ssc.stage_name` it should work as long as you don't have more than one Stage with the same name. Otherwise, you should add the ID of the Stage on both sub-queries and add the condition to the where using those IDs instead of the stage names.

### 2- You are missing the join condition between sub-queries

The reason why you need to add a `WHERE` condition or you get 20K results is because there is no `ON` for the INNER JOIN. That is to say you can put everything you add on the WHERE on that `ON`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ssh.stage_name, ssh.sh_al, ssh.sh_cat, ssc.time, ssc.M, ssc.P, ssc.B, ssc.Fin
FROM (
    SELECT s.ID stageID, s.stage_name, sh.sh_al, sh.sh_uid, sh.sh_cat
    FROM Shooter sh
    INNER JOIN Stage_Shooters stsh ON stsh.ShooterID = sh.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsh.StageID
) ssh
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.ID stageID, s.stage_name stageName, sc.time, sc.shtr, sc.miss M, sc.proc P, sc.bth B, sc.finalTime Fin
    FROM Score sc
    INNER JOIN Stage_Scores stsc ON stsc.ScoreID = sc.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsc.StageID
) ssc
ON ssh.sh_uid = ssc.shtr AND ssh.stageID = ssc.stageID;
```

### 3- You can probably make the whole thing with a single query

It looks like you can get the very same result you are getting with the following (shorter) query:

```
SELECT
    stage_name,
    sh_al,
    sh_cat,
    time,
    miss AS M,
    proc AS p,
    bth AS b,
    finalTime AS Fin
FROM
    Shooter AS sh
    JOIN Stage_Shooters AS stsh ON stsh.ShooterID = sh.ID
    JOIN Stage AS s ON s.ID = stsh.StageID
    JOIN Stage_Scores AS stsc ON stsc.StageID = s.ID
    JOIN Score AS sc ON stsc.ScoreID = sc.ID AND sc.shtr = sh.ID
```

Without an SQL Fiddle it is complicated to actually verify this but I'm pretty confident that it should work.

Comment: All 3 recommendations worked! Thanks. I can't believe I overlooked such a simple statement.

Answer (score 0):

Should Stage_Scores have a Stage_ShootersID instead of a StageID?

It looks like you want to be able to link a Score to a specific shooter, but your table design does not allow you to.

Comment: from what I could understand, the Scores table has a `shtr` field that matches one specific Shooter ID so that is actually covered (and the problem with the amount of results returned by the query)

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking I see both sets of queries have a join to the stage table. I'm guessing you probably need to select  the stage ID into both sets and then join both ssh and ssc on stage ID as well as shooter ID

```
SELECT ssh.stage_name, ssh.sh_al, ssh.sh_cat, ssc.time, ssc.M, ssc.P, ssc.B, ssc.Fin, s.ID as stageID
FROM (
    SELECT s.stage_name, sh.sh_al, sh.sh_uid, sh.sh_cat
    FROM Shooter sh
    INNER JOIN Stage_Shooters stsh ON stsh.ShooterID = sh.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsh.StageID
) ssh
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s.stage_name stageName, sc.time, sc.shtr, sc.miss M, sc.proc P, sc.bth B, sc.finalTime Fin, s.ID as stageID
    FROM Score sc
    INNER JOIN Stage_Scores stsc ON stsc.ScoreID = sc.ID
    INNER JOIN Stage s ON s.ID = stsc.StageID
) ssc
WHERE ssh.sh_uid = ssc.shtr
AND ssh.stageID = ssc.stageID
ORDER BY ssh.sh_al
```